# parent process and child process timing

Tags: c++, c, process, parent-child

Hi I have a simple question, however the timing issue is troubling me. Assume this is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int p = fork();
    if (p==0) {
        printf("ok\n");
        sleep(1);
    } else {
        printf("hey!");
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("done!");
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, will "done!" always be executed twice when the sleep is 1sec for both parent and child. Because I notice that when I increase the sleep to 10 seconds in the child process (p==0 case), I only see "done!" once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think when you increase sleep time parent process exited faster and stdout file descriptor closed. note that child and parent process shared their file descriptors.

if you want you can use [`_exit()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) in your parent process so when it exited, child process file descriptors will not be closed. in this way after 10 sec you see "done!" in your terminal. for use of this method you must use `printf("done!\n")` to flush your buffer manually because `_exit()` did not flush your buffer.

If you want you can use something like [`wait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) in your parent process to issue wait on your child process.

Comment: But will done always be printed twice event at sleep(1)?

Comment: No there's no guarantees, you need to wait() as suggested in answer